# Share Camera video on Google glass to PC

Tags: video, share, google-glass

Can any one let me know how to share video from Camera on Google Glass to an PC. 
Wanted to have a live share, may be over the internet.

Thanks,
Mohan

Answer (score 0):

There is an application on Glassware called [Livestream](http://new.livestream.com/producer/glass) which allows to stream video from Google Glass and watch it on iOS, Android or Roku TV.